# In IEnumerable, how to return a default value when no value matches the condition?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a method that finds all of a specific value in an `IEnumerable` source and returns the **value** and **index**. At this time, I want to return the `default` value when there is no matching value, but I don't know how.

This is because you are using `yield return` instead of creating and returning a new collection like `List<T>.FindAll()`.

```cs
public static class Example
{
    public static IEnumerable<(T sought, int index)> FindAllOccurrence<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, T value)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source), "The argument is null");

        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value), "The argument is null");
        
        foreach (var pair in source.Select((e, i) => (e, i)))
        {
            if (pair.e.Equals(value))
            {
                yield return (pair.e, pair.i);
            }
        }

        // How do I use the if statement here?
        yield return (default(T), -1);
    }
}
```

When the code below is written, the statement `yield return (default(T), -1);` is also executed.

```cs
public static void Operation()
{
    var list = new List<int>
    {
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 3, 3
    };

    var enumerable = list.FindAllOccurrence(3);

    foreach (var (value, index) in enumerable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"value: {value}, index: {index}");
    }
}
```

How do I write a proper if statement to prevent that statement from being executed?

Comment: Please ask the question in a different way, the answer given doesn't match the question asked.

Comment: @Mordagel *Enigmativity* correctly understood and answered my problem. Please be more specific about what the problem is.

Comment: Your question was how to return a specific value not the default value. He didn't answer the question you asked.

Comment: @Mordagel I understood. The problem was the *title*, not the *content*. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
public static IEnumerable<(T sought, int index)> FindAllOccurrence<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, T value)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source), "The argument is null");

    if (value == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value), "The argument is null");

    return source.Where(e => e.Equals(value)).Select((e, i) => (e, i)).DefaultIfEmpty((default(T), -1));
}
```

---

I'd also write this as:

```
public static IEnumerable<(T sought, int index)> FindAllOccurrence<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, T value) =>
        source
            .Where(e => e.Equals(value))
            .Select((e, i) => (e, i))
            .DefaultIfEmpty((default(T), -1));
```

You get an exception already if `source` is `null` and it's not clear to me that you should get an exception if `value` is `null`.

---

If you want a direct answer to your question, here's how:

```
public static IEnumerable<(T sought, int index)> FindAllOccurrence<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, T value)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source), "The argument is null");

    if (value == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value), "The argument is null");

    var found = false;

    foreach (var pair in source.Select((e, i) => (e, i)))
    {
        if (pair.e.Equals(value))
        {
            found = true;
            yield return (pair.e, pair.i);
        }
    }

    if (!found)
        yield return (default(T), -1);
}
```